# C# Pinvoke SetFilePointer not setting desired value of pointer

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using createfile method of pinvoke to create a handle to a drive, but the while using the SafeFileHandle when I am trying to SetFilePointer it is setting it to a junk location.

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern ulong SetFilePointer([In] SafeFileHandle hFile, [In] long lDistanceToMove, ref IntPtr lpDistanceToMoveHigh, [In] EMoveMethod dwMoveMethod);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

dwCurrentFilePosition = SetFilePointer(diskHandle, 0, ref hWrite, EMoveMethod.Begin);
```

Even while setting it to zero as indicated in the above code it sets it to some location 348966092800

Any idea on this?

Comment: Your p/invoke signature is wrong. In Windows C++ a `long` is 32 bits. In C# a `long` is 64 bits. Use the signature from pinvoke.net. SetFilePointerEx is simpler.

Comment: In case of SetFilePointerEx the definition at PInvoke states:[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetFilePointerEx(
     SafeFileHandle hFile, long liDistanceToMove,
     out long lpNewFilePointer, uint dwMoveMethod); So here should we use long as new position?

Comment: Well yes, SetFilePointerEx uses 64 bit args. This is all well documented.